# JavaScript Return form httprequest function

Tags: javascript, httprequest

How to return a variable from a httpreq function?

```js
function getTrailerYoutube(movieName){
    var getVideoList = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=' 
       + movieName + '+Trailer&type=video&videoDuration=short&key=<mykey>'

    httpreq.get(getVideoList, function (err, res){
      if (err) return console.log(err);
       var moviefront = JSON.parse(movieback);
       var result = moviefront.video.videoId
       return result
    });

}

console.log(result); //undefined
```

I although tried a second function and a global variable, but I didn't got a result.

Comment: The callback function (`function(err, res){}`) is a callback for an asynchronous action. move `console.log(result);` to inside the callback function and you'll see the result.

Comment: Is `httpreq.get` a third party library function?

Comment: @stephenLast Thanks, i know, but it need the result in another function. 
@ MarkC. Yes, it a npm package [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/httpreq)